# How to focus a control in a form which is added on a panel of its parent form by tabbing index

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms

I'm working on winforms in c#. I have a form which loads other forms in its panel. Now my child forms have many textboxes.

I want to set focus on one of those textboxes by loading my children forms by setting tab index to zero.

But it isn't happening when i load my children forms. I have taken care of the tab stop properties & i also went through the tabbing order of the forms. But the problem is still there.

When i load children forms from startup it focuses zero indexed control. I guess my problem is that i am loading these forms in a panel of a parent form. Any solution to this problem?

Comment: Not so clear what you're doing anyway did you try to call .Select() on control you want to receive focus? By default focused control is the first enabled (and selectable) control in tab index and to change that you have to explicitly make another control selected.

Comment: Its like this:
I have a MainForm
   --it has a panel
     --panel loads TruckForm, it has textbox named txtTruck.


Now when my program starts Mainform opens.
Then i can press a button to load TruckForm.
Now when TruckForm loads i want my txtTruck to be focused.
Tab index of txtTruck is zero. But its not focused.

I dont want to code manually to do this.

Comment: Sorry but you have to do it manually. Why WinForms should give focus to another control? It doesn't. You don't have to explicitly give focus to txtTruck but **you have to** do it to TruckForm after it has been loaded and inserted in its container Panel.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Forms controls in the following list are not selectable. Controls derived from these controls are also not selectable.
Panel
GroupBox
PictureBox
ProgressBar
Splitter
Label
LinkLabel (when there is no link present in the control)

Focus is a low-level method intended primarily for custom control authors. Instead, application programmers should use the Select method or the ActiveControl property for child controls, or the Activate method for forms.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can set focus to a control in a form which is added on a panel of its parent form by  creating an instance of child form in the parent form and then setting focus to child form controls.
Make an instance of child form:
ChildForm formInstanceName = new ChildForm();

And then you can set the focus property for particular control as:
formInstanceName .controlname.Focus();

And before doing this make sure you add the child form to the respective panel.

Here is the snippet of the code I used:
Form1 childform1 = new Form1();//creating an instance of child form
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
Panel2.Controls.Clear();//To clear existing controls on panel
  Panel2.Controls.Add(childform1); // To add child form controls on the panel.
  childform1 .textbox1.Focus(); //To set focus to control of child form
```

}

I hope this helps you..